# Difficulty finding Expectation of a special function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, integral-equations

I have a special function given as:

$${\rm f}\left(r\right) ={1 \over \beta\lambda}\,2^{r/\beta}
\exp\left({\left[2^{r/\beta} - 1\right]K \over \lambda}\right)$$

I should find the Expectation of the random variable $r$. Mathematica was not able to solve the associated Integral function. So it returns:

$$ \int_0^{\infty}\left\{{1 \over \beta\lambda}\,2^{r/\beta}
\exp\left({\left[2^{r/\beta} - 1\right]K \over \lambda}\right)\right\}\ r\,{\rm d}r $$

Does anyone recognize how I can reduce this function so I can solve it further?

==== Edit =====

This is the code I tried:

```
Integrate[ r*fr, {r, 0, \Infinity}, Assumptions->{K>=1, \lambda >=0, \beta >=0}]
```

Comment: Please post the code you've already tried.

Comment: It looks like unless `K/lambda <0` your integral is not convergent. Also, it doesn't look like `f[r]` it's normalized.

Comment: Yes right. That's what @ubpdqn showed - $Re[\frac{a3}{a2}]<0$, that is $Re[\frac{K}{λ}]<0$. Unfortunately, I think I have a bigger problem, because both $K$ and $λ$ are positive in my model.

$f(r)$ is actually correct. Although I removed a product term $K Log[2]$ from $f(r)$ which on testing does not seem to have any major effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral is conditionally convergent.
You can progress using substitution:
$u=2^{\frac{r}{b}}\iff r= b\log_2 u $ 
Hence,$\frac{dr}{du}=\frac{b}{u\ln 2}$

You can do these substitutions in Mathematica:

```
f[r_, b_, la_, k_] := 2^(r/b) Exp[k (2^(r/b) - 1)/la]/(b la)
exp = f[x, a1, a2, a3] /. {2^(x/a1) -> u};
ex = D[a1 Log[2, u], u];
ans = Integrate[a1 Log[2, u] exp ex, {u, 1, Infinity}]
```

The symbolic integral is thence:

```
ConditionalExpression[-((a1 E^(-(a3/a2)) Gamma[0, -(a3/a2)])/(
  a3 Log[2]^2)), Re[a3/a2] < 0]
```

Now you can compare numerically:

```
N@Integrate[r f[r, 1, -1, 1], {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

yields

-1.24122

and using the symbolic integral:

```
N[ans /. {a1 -> 1, a2 -> -1, a3 -> 1}]
```

yields: -1.24122

A small sample:

```
Grid[Table[{1, j, 1, N@ans /. {a1 -> 1, a2 -> j, a3 -> 1}, 
   Integrate[r f[r, 1, j, 1], {r, 0, Infinity}]}, {j, 
   Range[-1, -0.1, 0.1]}], 
 Dividers -> {{False, False, False, True, {False}}, None}]
```

[image]

I arbitrarily chose some parameters to illustrate. Further insights regarding convergence can be obtained:

```
Manipulate[ 
 Plot[{r f[r, 1, j, 1], r f[r, 1, 1, j]}, {r, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 10}, 
  Epilog -> Text[Style[j, 20, Red], {6, 5}]], {j, -1, 1, 0.15}]
```

[image]

Obviously the parameter constraints (regions of interest) are up to users intention.

Comment: Great! Interesting work. It appears to me that $\lambda$ implies $a2$ which appears to be $ < 0$. This seems to contradict our original assumption that $\lambda >= 0$. Am I right?

Comment: @Methyl see update

Comment: You're quite correct. The solution here is conditioned on $Re[a3/a2] < 0$, that is $Re[\frac{K}{\lambda}] < 0$. Unfortunately, I think I have a bigger problem, both $K$ and $\lambda$ are positive in my model.

Comment: Let me be the first to give well-deserved +1, a typically neat and clean answer by you.